# How make, that every page with section start have an empty style

Tags: xetex, etoolbox, patching

There is some problem, that I can't understand.

I want, that each page with start section has `empty` style

```
\appto\section{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

I get an error

```
! Argument of \thispagestyle has an extra }.
```

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. What exactly is the end goal here? Especially `This work only for first page. Other pages has no empty style.` does not make sense given what you wrote at the start. And please always make full examples.

Comment: you really don't want to *append* something to \section. \section is still looking for its arguments and will get quite confused if it finds the \thispagestyle.

Comment: @daleif, I want each page on which a new section starts to have an empty style

Comment: Then what do you mean by `Other pages has no empty style`?

Comment: @daleif, I mean, it still only works for the first page. Others pages, where the section starts, do not have an empty style

Comment: The definition of \section depends on the document class, and I don't know of any which start a new page with each section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested method of doing

```
\preto{\section}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

doesn't actually work. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\preto{\section}{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\kant

\section{Second step}

\kant

\kant[1]\kant[2][1-4]

\section{Third step}

\kant

\end{document}
```

If you look at pages 5 and 6, you'll see that the footer on page 5 is empty, but the section starts at page 6.

[image]

What's the problem? The page breaking mechanism is asynchronous and in the case of section three, the `\thispagestyle{empty}` command is digested before TeX can actually know that the section title has to be moved on the next page.

You need to move the instruction to a point when the page breaking decision has already been made (difficult task) or make preventative play:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}

\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\needspace{5\baselineskip}\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\kant

\section{Second step}

\kant

\kant[1]\kant[2][1-4]

\section{Third step}

\kant

\end{document}
```

With `\needspace{5\baselineskip}` we ensure that the `\section` command will be seen when the new page has started.

[image]